# python runs slow while executing below piece of code

Tags: linux, python-2.7

```
tag_api=”htpps://url....”  
json_data=requests.get(tag_api)  
length=len(json_data[‘tags’])  
line=0  
while length>=2:  
    if line<=lenght-1:  
        with open(‘file.txt’,’a’) as fp:  
            fp.write(json_data[‘tags’][line][‘name’])  
            line=line+1
```

While I run this code it gets slow at while loop. Do you suggest what could be the issue?

`{ { 
     { "id": "", 
       "category": "",
       "type": "",
       "tags": { "id": "", "name": "" }
               { "id": "", "name": "" } }, 
     { "id": "", 
       "category": "",
       "type": "",
       "tags": { "id": "", "name": "" } },
     { "id": "", 
       "category": "",
       "type": "", 
       "tags": { "id": "", "name": "" } },
     { "id": "", 
       "category": "",
       "type": "", 
       "tags": { "id": "", "name": "" }
               { "id": "", "name": "" } },
 } }`

I am trying to get the tags that have more than two index and write to a file

Comment: There are several spelling errors. Did you type in the code, or does it really look this way?

Comment: @chrisz thank you for correction. I have to type the code and had spelling errors. Do you see any issue with code?

Comment: @Raghu just copy and paste, there are still quite a few errors.  I just formatted it.

Comment: {
  {
    {
      "id": "",
      "category": "",
      "type": "",
      "tags": {
        "id": "",
        "name": ""
      }
      {
        "id": "",
        "name": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "category": "",
      "type": "",
      "tags": {
        "id": "",
        "name": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "category": "",
      "type": "",
      "tags": {
        "id": "",
        "name": ""
      }
    },
  ]
}
}


I am trying to print the tags that have more than two index and the my json file looks like above

Comment: @usr2564301 sorry did not get your question.

Comment: Just "python" as tag would be enough, if the code is not specific to one or the other.

Comment: got it..updated :)

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file (and closing it) are quite slow operations. Since it's the same file every time, you should move the opening out as far as possible.

Comment: thanks @Arndt Jonasson
Do you see a better code to get the tags that have more than two index..